# Keeping track of strings drawn on JPanel using Paint in Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouselistener

So, I have this simple program that paints a string on JPanel using `g2.drawString("Hello world", 40, 120)`. Basically, I want to be able to keep track of **many** strings on the JPanel at once. I'm not sure how to do this. For example, I would want to have an ArrayList of objects that keep track of these strings.

I want to be able to click-and-drag these strings so I will need to know there locations, etc.

Right now, using `g2.drawString`, it only draws the string. I want something like `gw.draw(myStringObject)`. Not sure if this is a dumb request but this is what I am looking for. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawSimpleText extends JPanel {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 96);
        g2.setFont(font);

        g2.drawString("Hello world", 40, 120);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(new DrawSimpleText());
        f.setSize(300, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1, cross posted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/641794/GUI/java/Keeping-track-strings-drawn-JPanel#2946878

Comment: @peeskillet Unfortunate call on the [tag:drawstring] tag.  It is quite specific (to .Net).

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry didn't read the tag info. I've seen it used before for swing and just _assumed_. Never again :-)

Comment: @peeskillet *"I've seen it used before for swing"*  Yep, just as I was looking down the list of questions of that tag, it seemed to have many entries involving Java.  Don't know in that case if it is better to edit the tag description to mention Java as well, or go through the list and bulk edit it out for questions tagged Java.  In fact, even typing that was so tiring that I don't even think I'll bother to 'take it to Meta' to find out which is considered better. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I say Meta. Not just for this tag, but many like it. One interesting thing I noticed the other day was the [jscrollpane](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jscrollpane/info). I saw it all by itself on a question so I automatically tagged the post as Java-Swing. I later found out it was incorrect. Not sure if this double meaning tag is a good idea, but who is to decide who owns it?

Comment: @peeskillet  Huh.. I'd never realized that the jscrollpane tag was shared between languages.  In the applet tag description I took pains to point out that the original meaning of applet is 'small application' and it is gradually coming back to that definition.  So when I see people tagging it for an OS config. tool like the 'Unix localization applet' I figure a) it is not written in Java and b) to leave it be (still added to the post).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to click-and-drag these strings so I will need to know there locations, etc.

Use a JLabel, then you can just drag them like any component.

See [Component Mover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for one way to do the dragging.